# Kotlin generics cast unchecked warning

Tags: generics, kotlin, casting

I have this piece of code

```
inline fun <reified T>store(dataList: List<T>) {
            when (T::class.java) {
                MyClass::class.java -> this.sasses = dataList as List<MyClass>
```

The `as List<MyClass>` issues a warning:

> Unchecked cast: List to List

I'm pretty sure my code is safe but how to silence this warning?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `filterIsInstance` to avoid this warning. like

```
inline fun <reified T>store(dataList: List<T>) {
            when (T::class.java) {
                MyClass::class.java -> this.sasses = dataList.filterIsInstance<MyClass>()
```